# Button doing post back of one user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure I'm in the right area but I will give this a try.

I have an asp.net page with a C sharp code behind page and I have a submit button to save a form on the page. Now my issue is that I have 500 users that don't have any problems and 1 user that has to click it 5 or 6 times to get it to fire. It will postback everytime but will not save.

I can post some code if need be, I've looked at everything and her record and computer is no different then anyone else's just looking for ideas.

**All** and any help is welcomed thank you everyone.

EDIT:

all users must be using IE7 or better

```
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    button.EnableViewState = true;

    InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e);
}

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.button.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
}

protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((Session["value"] == null) || (Session["value"] == "")))
    {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        checkNoteValues("Inc");
    }
}
```

Comment: You will certainly need to add some code...

Comment: Info on what browser they are using may also prove helpful.

Comment: This could just be a bad connection -- malformed request will show a postback but not be able to decrypt maybe.

Comment: have you logged anything? could you tell us what's happening? you say the page is posted back: how do you know? How is it saved... what does "save" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Lock the screen with a DIV;
2. Disable the button after the click;
3. Use the "Synchronizer Token" pattern;

Options 1 and 2 are vulnerable to one (or more) page reload (F5).
Option 3 is more robust and, in theory, is foolproof.

Soon I'll post sample code for 1 and 3.

EDITED:

Helper class to "Synchronizer Token"

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace TestDivLockScreen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to "Synchronizer Token Pattern".
    /// </summary>
    public class SynchronizerToken
    {
        private static readonly string SESSION_KEY_TOKEN = "TestDivLockScreen.SynchronizedToken.SESSION_KEY_TOKEN";

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a new token and positions it for validation of next request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string NewToken()
        {
            string token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(SESSION_KEY_TOKEN, token);
            return token;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the value of the current token. Renew if the current token is null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string CurrentToken()
        {
            string token = HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_KEY_TOKEN] as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                token = NewToken();
            }

            return token;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the token matches the token of last call to NewToken.
        /// The removal of the token is only made after a new call NewToken.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsCurrentToken(string token)
        {
            string currentToken = HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_KEY_TOKEN] as string;
            if (currentToken == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (currentToken.Equals(token))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Do the same as IsCurrentToken. However loads a new "token value"
        /// in the session. Is "Thread Safe"!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsCurrentTokenRenew(string token)
        {
            lock (HttpContext.Current.Session)
            {
                string currentToken = CurrentToken();
                NewToken();
                if (currentToken.Equals(token))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Define a hidden field on the page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HdfSyncToken" runat="server" />
```

On code behind:

```
protected void Pre_Render(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //repositioning token
    this.HdfSyncToken.Value = SynchronizerToken.CurrentToken();

    //Refresh GridView
    this.GrvRecords.DataSource = this.Records;
    this.GrvRecords.DataBind();
}

protected void BtnInsertST_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Abort second execution for the same value of the token
    if (!SynchronizerToken.IsCurrentTokenRenew(this.HdfSyncToken.Value))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Request has already been answered!');</script>");
    }
    //Insert Record (token validation OK)
    else
    {
        this.InsertRecord();
    }
}
```

Conplete source (VS2005): [q_11402631.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/q_11402631.7z)