# SynchronizerToken In ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was wondering if anyone can help me out.  I have an application with several links.  One thing I have been noticing is that when a user clicks a link more than once I can get a response multiple times.  This may result in a record being committed to a database table multiple times and cannot happen.  From what research I've done, it looks like this is an example of when I would use SynchronizerToken's but this is new to me and i have no experience using them.  I did find this example: [Button doing post back of one user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401554/button-doing-post-back-of-one-user/11402631#11402631)

Is this method the best possible one to use for this scenario?  I haven't really seen any other examples out there.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scrapping the idea of tokens and just disabled forms when a post back occurs.

Answer (score 0):

How about disabling the UI element right before postback so multiple clicks are not possible?

Comment: I thought of that but my supervisor would prefer me using tokens